# Selection does not stick in AngularJS MultiSelect Binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to display selected values from a multiselect as separate objects in my view, meaning selected values will appear somewhere else on the form; the actual multiselect will be hidden, it's only needed to post selected values so they can be bound to a viewmodel server-side (ASP.NET MVC).

This appears to be working. However, AngularJS will prefix IDs with 'string:' so I have to use `track by`. If I do, the multiselect starts acting strange, that is if I select an option that option is immediately deselected again unless I click that option twice. I haven't got a clue what is going on there.

Here's the code on [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/1WpruZ5n4cbQwRzuaezh?p=preview), anybody got an idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be an issue of the ng-options directive (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6564).

I also found some information in the angularjs docs:

**"Be careful when using select as and track by in the same expression."**

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

I forked your plunker and used a `<options>` tag with ng-repeat instead:

https://plnkr.co/edit/uH4hGgUGjvAxcBt3bViT?p=preview

Comment: Two equally well working answers was a tough call, I went with this solution because it was the least invasive, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies with the generator pattern `value.id as value.name` which has been broken for a while now, despite what the documentation claims.

[I have forked your plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/S8PfP3QY6UZbM8MDDvgx?p=preview) and changed the `select` tag to this:-

```
<select id="tracking" multiple="multiple" ng-model="vm.selected" 
  ng-options="value.name for value in vm.values track by value.id">
```

If you now inspect this element in your browser you will see there are no unwanted "string:" prefixes on the `option` elements' `value` attributes.

For your peace of mind I have also written a function to extract the values that will be sent to the server if the form was submitted.

However, as a consequence of my change, the items in the `vm.selected` array are no longer string IDs, but the actual objects themselves. So remember to add `.id` to code that reference array members, eg. `vm.selected[ i ].id` instead of `vm.selected[ i ]`

Comment: Ok, so it is indeed a bug in Angular. Thanks for the background information and a working solution. Although I'll go with the second proposed solution I'll adopt some changes you made to the plunkr so I voted this answer up as well.